# Angular 2 FlexLayout - Change page content with breakpoints

Tags: javascript, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'm learning Angular and right now I'm to make a login form, similar to Gmail page using Angular2, Angular Material and Flex-Layout (all from Angular).
So far everything is fine the only problem is I don't know how to change the card `div` so it fills the entire screen when using `fxFlex.lt-sm` like on the Gmail page.
How can I achieve this?

What I've done so far:
https://plnkr.co/edit/X8Rs7QHaMG9XzB1LTkbR?p=preview

#### Normal card

[image]

#### No card

[image]

Comment: More than images, your code snippet or even better a simplified plunker could help us to help you :)

Comment: @Vega I'm making the plunker right now, I'll post it here when I'm done

Comment: @Vega here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/X8Rs7QHaMG9XzB1LTkbR?p=preview

Comment: I am not very familliar with material2, but I would suggest to put the width of the div just before md-card to 100vw and the md-card width to calc(100% - 2*the margin)

Answer (score 1):

If the container of your form has the width of the page then setting fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" should work. But if you're using fxLayout=column instead of row then it will set your max-height to 100% so you would need to set the width manually.

If this doesn't help, please post your html code and I'll update my answer

EDIT

```
<!-- Card -->
  <div style="width: 100%" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <md-card fxFlex="448px" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
```

Seems to work if you modify like that